# Ansync thread from WCF RESTful Service

Tags: multithreading, wcf

We have created a WCF RESTful service for a WPF(UI) Application. The UI sends a request to the WCF Service which then invokes a suitable method in BLL, which in turn  invokes a method in DAL. All these layers have been separated using IOC/DI.

Now, for a new feature, we want that when a new object of a certain type is added to the database, it should go through 3 steps which would be performed in a separate thread.

That is, if service sends a request to BLL to add a new object OBJ to the database, the BLL should save the object into database through the DAL and then initiate a new thread to perform a some actions upon the object without blocking the WCF Request.

But whenever we try to do so by starting a new thread in the BLL, the application crashes. It is so because the 'InRequestScope' object of the database context has been disposed and the thread cannot update the database. Also the WCF request does not ends until the thread is completed, although the return value has been provided and the BLL method has completed execution.

Any help would be much valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution and explanation for this behavior. Turns out to be a rather silly one.

Since I was creating a thread from the BLL (with IsBackground = true;), the parent thread (originated by the service request) was waiting for this thread to end. And when both the threads ended, the response was sent back to the client. And the solution, well, use a BackgroundWorker instead, no rocket science, just common sense.

And for the disposing of context, since the objects were InRequestScope, and the request had ended. So every time a Repository required a UnitOfWork (uow/context), it would generate a new context and end it as soon as the database request was complete. And the solution would be, create a uow instance, store in a variable, pass it to the repository required to be used, and force all repositories to use the same uow instance than creating a new one for itself.

Answer (score 0):

This seem more of a client-side concern than a service-side concern. Why not have the client make asynchronous requests to WCF service since this automatically provides multi-threaded access to the service.

The built-in System.Net.WebClient (since you're access a webHttpBinding or WCF Web API endpoint) can be used asynchronously. This [blog post](http://logicbomblabs.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/asynchronous-webclient-requests/) gives a quick overview of how it is done. Although this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700359.aspx) seems to apply to file I/O, about three quarters down, there is a detailed explanation on coding asynchronous WebClient usage.

Comment: We more of wanted to have a process running on the server so that client does not keep waiting for the response. More over the server side process would mean that it would be carried out even if client shuts down. And also would reduce the traffic on the server.